# Magento 2, add a custom block with page builder

Tags: magento

I have Magento 2.4.3.

I created a custom block inside a custom module.
I tried to use it inside a custom layout of a custom theme
It works.
Now i want use it with page builder.
In back-end when i try to select the block to insert it inside a page the block not exists, how can i register it to show it in list?
[image]

MyCode

app\code\Goteam\HelloWorld\Block\Display.php

```
namespace Goteam\HelloWorld\Block;
class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    }
 
}
```

\app\code\Goteam\HelloWorld\registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Goteam_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: no, i created a shortcode

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible (yet) to register to show it in the (static) block list or the sidebar. I've been looking into the core module source code and it seems the elements from the page builder are built using `ui_components`.

You can however add it inside a HTML code block using a "shortcode":

```
{{block class="Goteam\HelloWorld\Block\Display" name="hello" template="Goteam_HelloWorld::template.phtml" area="frontend"}}
```

[image]

Comment: yes i find only this way

Comment: @MarioProject there must be a way to declare the ui_component parts, their related classes and layout files in a custom module, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation. I really want this so I will be sleuthing in the source code and I might report back.